# Sound card installs and runs on one OS in a dual boot but not the other

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I've got a strange problem where I've got a dual boot system running exactly the same hardware barring the one running on an M.2 drive and the other a normal SSD, both are running W10 Pro and both are fairly fresh installs.

On the first drive the sound card installs as expected without issue, but after 10+ attempts multiple reboots the second OS is refusing to recognize the sound card.

The second OS which is refusing the sound card has no unusual apps that could be interfering, in fact the sound card was one of the first things I was trying to install everything else seems to be working as expected.

I've checked for errors in the **event viewer** but nothing relevant is standing out as obvious.

---

### System setup:

- **Microsoft Windows 10 Pro - Build 18363**
- **i7-5960X CPU**
- **MB: MSI X99A SLI PLUS**
- **64GB DDR4**
- **OS 1 drive: 970 Evo 512GB**
- **OS 2 drive: Crucial MX500 250GB**
- **Sound card: Line 6 UX2 Studio**

> I'm ***not desperate*** for a solution as that OS is just a back up, but it's a weird problem that makes no sense and would love to have some insight as to the cause.

I've done tons of trouble shooting and ruled out all of the usual suspects I could think of, uninstalled, reinstalled, clean boots, device manager, yada yada. Over 20 years recording music I've had to deal withe plenty of head scratchers when it comes to sound cards misbehaving. I'm used to being the person people come to if they've got audio problems, but this one has me totally stumped. lmao

Comment: What does it say in the device manager? Which version of windows10 are you running on both disks? How did you install the drivers? Have you tried installing the drivers when the m.2 disk is unplugged/disabled?

Comment: As stated device manger just gives generic error, device not working as expected, no helpful output, both running w10 build as listed above, I cannot try that as the m.2 is attached to the motherboard and contains the boot record, besides it would require dismantling most of the machine to access so not something I'm willing to do for testing. I installed the drivers via the sound card driver installer